How do I map new SQL Server functions to SQL Alchemy's ORM
I want to call SUSER_SNAME using SQLAlchemy's ORM. I can call the user() function like this:
res = connection.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.functions.user())

But If I replace user() with suser_sname() I get this:

AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.sql.functions' has no attribute
'suser_sname'

I know that I can just execute sqlalchemy.text("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()") but I would like to add a custom function to achieve this. Is this possible?

I've removed the SQL Server tag, because its not SQL Server expertise you need...

sqlalchemy.sql.func.SUSER_SNAME()

@python_user yep that worked. Cheers! Is there documentation for that?

Any name can be given to func. If the function name is unknown to SQLAlchemy, it will be rendered exactly as is.

Thanks, feel free to add this as an answer and I'll give it a tick.

yw, just did that @quant

From the docs

Any name can be given to func. If the function name is unknown to SQLAlchemy, it will be rendered exactly as is.

So in your case
from sqlalchemy import func
func.SUSER_SNAME()

